# Unable to start Oracle WebLogic Server

Tags: java, weblogic

I am trying to start oracle WebLogic Server 10.3.6 using `startWebLogic.cmd` located in domain but I get the error below;

> \Java\jdk1.7.0_60 was unexpected at this time.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you have java installed in either `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_23` or `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23` folder.

Path can't take a space in it, so you need to replace this `PROGRA~2` instead of `Program Files(86)`; it's the Windows short name for the same folder.

Similarly, use `PROGRA~1` for the `Program Files` folder.